# PyQt5 window automatically closes after running for a few seconds - "Process finished with exit code -1073741819 (0xC0000005)"

Tags: python, oop, pyqt, pyqt5

I am trying to make a desktop application with PyQt5 which utilizes the webcam. I saw a YouTube video in which the guy used threading to achieve that. I modified the code for my use case. The modified code is below: -

```
import sys
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *
from PyQt5.QtGui import *
from PyQt5.QtCore import *
import cv2


class MainWindow(QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.setWindowTitle("Ayyo")

        self.GL = QGridLayout()

        self.feedLabel = QLabel()
        self.GL.addWidget(self.feedLabel, 0, 0, 1, 2)

        self.lineEdit = QLineEdit()
        self.GL.addWidget(self.lineEdit, 1, 0, 1, 1)

        self.button1 = QPushButton("Confirm")
        self.button1.clicked.connect(self.confirm)
        self.GL.addWidget(self.button1, 1, 1, 1, 1)

        self.textEdit = QTextEdit()
        self.GL.addWidget(self.textEdit, 2, 0, 2, 1)

        self.button2 = QPushButton("Clear")
        self.button2.clicked.connect(self.clear)
        self.GL.addWidget(self.button2, 2, 1, 1, 1)

        self.button3 = QPushButton("Copy")
        self.GL.addWidget(self.button3, 3, 1, 1, 1)

        self.webcam = Webcam()
        self.webcam.start()
        self.webcam.ImageUpdate.connect(self.ImageUpdateSlot)

        self.setLayout(self.GL)

        self.show()

    def ImageUpdateSlot(self, image):
        self.feedLabel.setPixmap(QPixmap.fromImage(image))

    def confirm(self):
        current = self.textEdit.toPlainText()
        self.textEdit.setPlainText(current + self.lineEdit.text())

    def clear(self):
        self.textEdit.setPlainText("")


class Webcam(QThread):
    ImageUpdate = pyqtSignal(QImage)
    
    def run(self):
        self.ThreadActive = True
        vid = cv2.VideoCapture(0)

        while True:
            ret, frame = vid.read()
            frame1 = cv2.cvtColor(frame, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB)
            image = QImage(frame1, frame1.shape[1], frame1.shape[0], frame1.strides[0], QImage.Format_RGB888)
            self.ImageUpdate.emit(image)


app = QApplication(sys.argv)
mw = MainWindow()
# mw.show()
sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

When I run this, the actual program runs fine but it automatically closes after a few seconds with

> Process finished with exit code -1073741819 (0xC0000005)

Blockquote

The strange thing is while debugging the code in PyCharm, it didn't close. But whenever I run the code, it automatically closes after a few seconds. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Have you tried running the code from a terminal? And if so, does it show you an error message?

Answer (score 0):

These are always difficult to troubleshoot, but I have found that you should avoid using QThreads while initializing the application as it sometimes causes random shutdowns.

Try:

- Initialize the application and show it.
- Run the webcam Class (although I suggest you replace this with a function)

If you want to have this feature threaded so it doesn't lock the UI, take a look at QThreadPool for PyQt5 (https://www.mfitzp.com/tutorials/multithreading-pyqt-applications-qthreadpool/)

Comment: Could you maybe elaborate on how to change this to a function?

Comment: Once you implement the QThreadPool class in my link, you can call a function as a thread.  worker = Worker(self.camera_function) then run it using self.threadpool.start(worker). You can also connect any signals for returning a value or completing the thread - worker.signals.result.connect(self.function_to_send_result)

Answer (score -2):

Use QThreadPool

Here's an example of using QThreadPool in PyQt5:

```
import sys
from PyQt5.QtCore import QThreadPool, QRunnable, pyqtSignal,         QObject, QTimer
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QMainWindow, QLabel, QVBoxLayout, QPushButton, QWidget


class WorkerSignals(QObject):
    finished = pyqtSignal()

class Worker(QRunnable):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.signals = WorkerSignals()

def run(self):
    import time
    time.sleep(5)  # Simulating a long-running task
    self.signals.finished.emit()

class MainWindow(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

        self.setWindowTitle("QThreadPool Example")
        self.setGeometry(100, 100, 400, 200)

        self.central_widget = QWidget()
        self.setCentralWidget(self.central_widget)

        self.label = QLabel("Waiting")
        self.button = QPushButton("Start Thread Pool")
        self.button.clicked.connect(self.start_thread_pool)

        layout = QVBoxLayout()
        layout.addWidget(self.label)
        layout.addWidget(self.button)
        self.central_widget.setLayout(layout)

        self.threadpool = QThreadPool()

    def start_thread_pool(self):
        self.label.setText("Thread Pool Started")
        self.button.setEnabled(False)

        # Submitting tasks to the thread pool
        for _ in range(5):
            worker = Worker()
            worker.signals.finished.connect(self.worker_finished)
            self.threadpool.start(worker)

    def worker_finished(self):
        QTimer.singleShot(0, lambda: self.label.setText("All tasks completed"))
        self.button.setEnabled(True)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    window = MainWindow()
    window.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

In this example, we create a Worker class that inherits from QRunnable. Each worker simulates a long-running task (5 seconds sleep) and emits a finished signal when the task is completed. We connect this signal to a slot in the main window (worker_finished) where we update the label to indicate that all tasks are completed.

When the "Start Thread Pool" button is clicked, we create multiple instances of Worker and submit them to the QThreadPool using the start() method. The thread pool then manages the execution of these tasks efficiently.

The main differences between `QThread` and `QThreadPool` in PyQt (or Qt in general) lie in their purposes and usage scenarios:

1. **QThread**:

   - Represents a single thread of execution.
   - Typically used for running a single task or operation that needs to be executed asynchronously or in the background.
   - Directly manages the lifecycle of a single thread, including starting, pausing, and stopping it.
   - Provides lower-level control over individual threads, allowing developers to implement custom threading behavior.
2. **QThreadPool**:

   - Represents a pool of threads that can be used to execute multiple tasks concurrently.
   - Suitable for scenarios where there are multiple similar tasks to be executed in parallel, such as handling multiple network requests or processing multiple data items simultaneously.
   - Manages a pool of worker threads and assigns tasks to available threads for execution, thus providing better resource utilization.
   - Provides a higher-level abstraction compared to `QThread`, abstracting away the details of thread management and allowing developers to focus on defining tasks to be executed.

In summary, while `QThread` is suitable for managing individual threads and executing single tasks, `QThreadPool` is more appropriate for managing multiple tasks concurrently by efficiently utilizing a pool of threads. The choice between them depends on the specific requirements of the application and the nature of the tasks to be performed.

Comment: Posting AI-generated answers is [forbidden on this site](https://stackoverflow.com/help/ai-policy).